# Undefined method 'nested attribute' for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to to create 2 type of addresses: pick up address and delivery address. To do this I created a polymorphic address model which is associated to a listing and an order. I want to create the new address in the listings and orders views using fields. For some reason this only works when I create a listing, when I try to create an order I get undefined method 'address' for model order.

**Note:** Irrelevant code has been omitted from the snippets below.

address.rb

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end
```

listing.rb

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :orders
 has_one :pickup_address, as: :addressable, class_name: "Address", dependent: :destroy

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :pickup_address
end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :listing
 has_one :delivery_address, as: :addressable, class_name: "Address", dependent: :destroy

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :delivery_address
end
```

In my form views I have

**app/views/listings/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(setup_listing(@listing)) do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :description %>
 <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %>

 <%= f.label :price %>
 <%= f.text_field :price, class: 'form-control' %>

 <%= f.fields_for :pickup_address do |u| %>
    
    <%= u.label :city %>
    <%= u.text_field :city, class: 'form-control' %>
    
    <%= u.label :sector %>
    <%= u.text_field :sector, class: 'form-control' %>
    
    <%= u.label :line_1 %>
    <%= u.text_field :line_1, class: 'form-control' %>
    
    <%= u.label :line_2 %>
    <%= u.text_field :line_2, class: 'form-control' %>
    
   <% end %>
 <%= f.submit "submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<%end%>
```

**app/views/orders/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@listing, setup_order(@order)]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :delivery_address do |u| %>

  <%= u.label :city %>
  <%= u.text_field :city, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= u.label :sector %>
  <%= u.text_field :sector, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= u.label :line_1 %>
  <%= u.text_field :line_1, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= u.label :line_2 %>
  <%= u.text_field :line_2, class: 'form-control' %>

  <% end %>
 <%= f.submit "submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<%end%>
```

Note that in the order `form_for` function I use square brackets because I build the order from the listing.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :listings do
     resources :orders
  end
end
```

The `setup_order/listing` function comes from

**app/helpers/form_helper.rb**

```
 module FormHelper

    def setup_listing(listing)
      listing.build_pickup_address if listing.pickup_address.nil?
      listing
    end

    def setup_order(order)
       order.build_delivery_address if order.delivery_address.nil?
       order
    end

 end
```

which I use to create the new address in case this one does not already exist as suggested in [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/).

I made sure to add the address attributes to my params in the controllers.

**listings_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @listing = current_user.listings.build(listing_params)
    if @listing.save
      flash[:success] = "listing created!"
      redirect_to @listing
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
   .
   .
   
  private

  def listing_params
   params.require(:listing).permit(pickup_address_attributes: [:city,   :sector,:line_1, :line_2])
  end
```

**orders_controller.rb**

```
   .
   .
   def create
     @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
     @order = @listing.orders.build(order_params)
     if @order.save
       redirect_to listings_path
     else
      render 'new'
     end
   end
   .
   .
   private

   def order_params
     params.require(:order).permit(delivery_address_attributes: [:city, :sector, :line_1, :line_2])
   end
```

My error:

[image: My error]

**Full trace**

```
activemodel (5.0.0) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
activemodel (5.0.0) lib/active_model/validator.rb:149:in `block in validate'
activemodel (5.0.0) lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `each'
activemodel (5.0.0) lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `validate'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `public_send'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:547:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `catch'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `block in default_terminator'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in `block in halting'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
activemodel (5.0.0) lib/active_model/validations.rb:408:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (5.0.0) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `block in run_validations!'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
activemodel (5.0.0) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (5.0.0) lib/active_model/validations.rb:338:in `valid?'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:65:in `valid?'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:82:in `perform_validations'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:45:in `create'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
searchkick (1.3.5) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:153:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Can you show the error? Where are you getting undefined method 'address' for order?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the create controller, the only difference i can think of is that i use square brackets in the orders view for the form_for function. @eeeeeean

Comment: Check out the full trace. Do you have a callback in order.rb that refers to address?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking for @eeeeeean but i did not find anything mentioning address in the full trace report.

Comment: It looks like you have some validation or callback that is calling an address method. Maybe you can search your project for '.address' for example with ack? And restart your server for good measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to change the relationship from `has_one` to `has_many`, setting the default attribute name, to see if that error had changed.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  
  belongs_to :listing
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :delivery_address

end
```

I also made the changes in my controller and view, but again I was getting no method 'address' instead of 'addresses' as it should have been. Then I realize that somewhere I must have written address so I searched and indeed in the validations (which I omitted in the questions for considering them irrelevant) I still had a validation for address, here the actual code for the model.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  validates :address, :seller_id, :buyer_id, :listing_id, presence: true  
  
  belongs_to :listing
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User"
  
  has_one :delivery_address, as: :addressable, class_name: "Address", dependent: :destroy
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :delivery_address

  enum status: [ :ordered, :shipped, :delivered, :rated ]
  
end
```

So avoid omitting code in the questions and make sure to check places you wouldn't usually do so.